What does the Menu background depict?
In FF7 Rebirth your characters stand behind an interesting looking background image whenever you go to the menu and I am trying to find out what exactly this background is supposed to depict. When I started playing I thought this might be either something from Cosmo Canyon or the Temple of the Ancients, but after having now played through the entire game, I haven't seen any place inside any of the game's areas that looks like this. I also went and skimmed through playthroughs of the Temple in both Rebirth and the original game, but again didn't see anything that resembles this background.
People online have been speculating it looks like the Temple of the Ancients and I agree, it looks similar, but I didn't see anything inside the temple that looked exactly like this wall. I couldn't find anywhere that had these big black circles or that had this exact shade of beige, the temple seemed way more orange in its color scheme. Where in this game, or even in the original, can you find a place that looks like this menu background? If you cannot, then what is this background supposed to depict? Is it just some vague reference to the Temple or is there more to it?

